# How to solve MongoError: pool destroyed while connecting to CosmosDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, azure-cosmosdb

I have Node.js service in which I am using mongo-API to communicate with Document/Cosmos DB.
My service run's fine and performs all the crud operation but after 1 min some mongo error throws from the service.

```
/document-db-service/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:123
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                  ^
MongoError: pool destroyed
    at Pool.write (/document-db-service/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:922:12)
    at Cursor._find (/document-db-service/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:286:22)
    at nextFunction (/document-db-service/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:584:10)
    at Cursor.next [as _next] (/document-db-service/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:692:3)
    at fetchDocs (/document-db-service/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:856:10)
    at toArray (/document-db-service/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:883:3)
    at Cursor.toArray (/document-db-service/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:836:44)
    at exports.getDocsOfCollections (/document-db-service/services/collections.js:273:10)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/document-db-service/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/document-db-service/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
```

I am not able to understand why this error is coming up.Please suggest the changes that need to be done to resolve this error.

Comment: Wow.. I am also running into this same error since last night.  I'm seeing the connection work for ~10 seconds before getting that error.

Comment: How do you resolve that ??

Comment: I haven't otherwise I would have answered you.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, although I'm spinning up a new prototype today so this doesn't represent a regression for me.  I can avoid the issue by removing the `replicaSet=globaldb` from the connection string, but I suspect that's probably not a _good_ thing to do.

Comment: This issue has been recognized by Microsoft (https://feedback.azure.com/forums/599059-azure-cosmos-db-mongodb-api/suggestions/19361521-fix-bug-that-destroys-nodejs-mongodb-connection-po) but as of 6/27/2017 they have not updated it with any further details.

Comment: Quick update... the team has a fix and is being deployed with 9/2017 estimated roll out.  See https://feedback.azure.com/forums/599059-azure-cosmos-db-mongodb-api/suggestions/19361521-fix-bug-that-destroys-nodejs-mongodb-connection-po

Answer (score 6):

I run into the same problem, removed the replica set parameter in the connection string mongodb:
        `........./?ssl=true**&replicaSet=globaldb**`
then it worked fine

Comment: would be great if anybody explained the under-the-hood of why this works :|