# MongoError: connection timed out on Azure CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

My application runs on NodeJS 4.4.7 and uses MongoDB driver 2.2.31 (not Mongoose) to connect to Azure CosmosDB. This is how I connect to the DB:

```
var connectionString = 'mongodb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@yyy.documents.azure.com:10255/DB_NAME?ssl=true'
var options = {
    db: { j: false },
    server: { autoReconnect: true, socketOptions: { connectTimeoutMS: 300000 } },
};
require('mongodb').MongoClient.connect(connectionString, options, callback);
```

And I recently started experiencing the following error:

```
MongoError: connection X to http://yyy.documents.azure.com:10255 timed out
```

where X is a small integer (I've seen 8, 10, 29, and so on).

Some background info:

- Had no errors (for 30+ days) when I didn't have geo replication set up.
- Recently set up geo replication from the Azure portal (West US as a write region, East US as a read region).
- Started experiencing "no primary server available" error.
- Updated my mongodb driver from 2.0.49 to 2.2.31 and the error was gone, however immediately started experiencing "pool destroyed" error.
- Following [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44116534/how-to-solve-mongoerror-pool-destroyed-while-connecting-to-cosmosdb) solved the issue (i.e. remove `&replicaSet=globaldb`)
- After 3 days of zero issues, I started experiencing the above "connection timed out" error. First reported error was at around Aug 16 8:24 PM EST, and last error reported was at around Aug 17 6:40 AM EST.

I'm not sure if it is a temporary issue from Azure or there is something wrong in the way I connect to CosmosDB. Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This issue might be related to not setting client-side connection parameters properly. Could you please try to set these and see if it resolves the timeout issue?

```
MongoClientOptions.Builder optionsBuilder = new MongoClientOptions.Builder();
optionsBuilder.socketTimeout(10000);
optionsBuilder.maxConnectionIdleTime(60000);
optionsBuilder.heartbeatConnectTimeout(5000);
MongoClientURI mongoClientURI = new MongoClientURI(props.getMongoDbConnection(), optionsBuilder);
```

Comment: Thanks @alekseys, I would like to try your suggestion but I am having hard time finding equivalent variables in the MongoDB NodeJS driver. Could you please help me find `maxConnectionIdleTime`  and `heartbeatConnectTimeout` equivalents?

Comment: there are no strict equivalents in NodeJS driver. You might want to check out keepAlive option and possibly combination of others listed on http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/MongoClient.html#connect

Comment: Thanks. I am using `keepAlive`, `socketTimeoutMS` and `connectTimeoutMS` and will be monitoring if the same error occurs over the weekend.

Comment: @BH.Q Did setting those parameters help fix the error?